# Using a mutli parameter function as generic type of another function scala

Tags: scala

I have the following code

```
object Test {

  def bar: String => Double = {
    foo[String](_.toDouble)
  }

  def baz: (Double, Double) => Double = {
    foo[(Double, Double)] {
      case (d1, d2) => d1 + d2
    }
  }

  def foo[T](f: T => Double): T => Double = {
    f
  }
}
```

bar works with no trouble, as expected. I am trying to get a similar thing working with mutli parameter function as one of the inputs, but this doesn't work, because scala sees the `foo[(Double, Double)]` as a tuple type rather than as a function parameter. Is there any way to tell scala this is a function parameter, rather than a tuple?

the code: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/sCYyU6ziT3mKOhkBiofAaQ

Comment: Well, there is an easy fix make `baz` of type: `((Double, Double)) => Double` that is a function of a single argument _(which is a tuple)_. - The other way is impossible AFAIK.

Comment: It's just a very simplified example in this case, for the sake of the question. In reality, there will be a bunch of logic in foo that will augment the original function

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason this didn't work for you is that you don't access the two separate arguments to the `baz` method, which need to be packaged into a tuple before calling `foo`. (I think there's some discussion about being able to convert parameter lists to/from tuples, but that's not currently possible.) Try this definition instead:

```scala
object Test {
  def bar: String => Double = {
    foo[String](_.toDouble)
  }
  def baz: (Double, Double) => Double = {(p1, p2) =>
    foo[(Double, Double)] {
      case(d1, d2) => d1 + d2
    }((p1, p2))
  }
  def foo[T](f: T => Double): T => Double = f
}
```

If I understand your intent correctly, this would be used like this (in the *Scala REPL*):

```scala
scala> Test.bar("5.0")
val res0: Double = 5.0
                                                                                                                                    
scala> Test.baz(3.0, 5.0)
val res1: Double = 8.0
```

However, this seems a little muddled. If `bar` and `baz` store method references, then they should be declared `val`, instead of `def`:

```scala
object Test {
  val bar: String => Double = {
    foo[String](_.toDouble)
  }
  val baz: (Double, Double) => Double = {(p1, p2) =>
    foo[(Double, Double)] {
      case(d1, d2) => d1 + d2
    }((p1, p2))
  }
  def foo[T](f: T => Double): T => Double = f
}
```

Which has the same usage syntax and produces the same output:

```scala
scala> Test.bar("5.0")
val res2: Double = 5.0
                                                                                                                                    
scala> Test.baz(3.0, 5.0)
val res3: Double = 8.0
```

But even that is still fairly clumsy. `bar` is a reference to a function that takes a `String` and returns a `Double`, while `baz` is a reference to a function that takes two `Double`s and returns a `Double`. So why not just make `bar` and `baz` methods in their own right, instead of method references? This would produce:

```scala
object Test {
  def bar(s: String): Double = foo[String](_.toDouble)(s)

  def baz(p1: Double, p2: Double): Double = {
    foo[(Double, Double)] {
      case(d1, d2) => d1 + d2
    }((p1, p2))
  }

  def foo[T](f: T => Double): T => Double = f
}
```

which again is used in the same way:

```scala
scala> Test.bar("5.0")
val res4: Double = 5.0
                                                                                                                                    
scala> Test.baz(3.0, 5.0)
val res5: Double = 8.0
```

And, of course, `foo` itself is redundant, since it is identical to its argument. So this could all be written far more simply as just:

```scala
object Test {
  def bar(s: String): Double = s.toDouble

  def baz(p1: Double, p2: Double): Double = p1 + p2
}
```